# Which Schema.org type I should use for digital goods service?

Tags: schema.org

I have digital goods service running website, there are about 7000 unique electronic devices listed on my web, but my service is about to provide some kind of digital keys for these electronic products i.e. I am not selling those physical electronic products, but some keys for these devices, to make them running well.

What is the most appropriate Schema.org type I should use taking into account that google supports and understands it.

Currently I use http://schema.org/Product - is it ok?

Comment: Unclear... What does it mean? clarify...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) type is also meant for digital products or services. Its description gives as example:

> an episode of a TV show streamed online

In case it’s software that comes with a key, you could use the [`SoftwareApplication`](https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) type in addition to `Product`, and the [`availableOnDevice`](https://schema.org/availableOnDevice) property to state which hardware the software is for.

Schema.org has no type for representing software licenses/keys.